# When moving a file in Pycharm, it is automatically added in git. How can I disable this behavior?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, pycharm

I am using Pycharm 2018.3.  Currently when I add or remove a file, I am prompted with a dialog like this that allows me to add the file to git immediately.

[image]

I have configured this in the settings to never add it to source-control:

[image]

Currently when I move or rename a file, it is automatically staged in git.  How can I disable this behavior?

Before committing code, I like to stage it manually and look at every change.  By auto-adding this file, this often disrupts my workflow and causes me to add changes that I did not intend to commit.

Comment: This looks like a configuration file persistence problem. Could you set the value to "Show options...", restart the IDE, and set it back to "Do not add"? Remember to "Apply" and then "OK". Just to be sure.

Comment: @LppEdd - This config only controls adds, **not moves or renames**

Comment: You haven't understood. Set "When files are created" option to the "Show options...", restart, and set it back

Answer (score 2):

The highlighted configuration in settings controls only the addition of newly created files and does not affect moves and renames.

The goal of this setting is not, however, to allow doing everything from the command line instead of the UI. Thus, there is no similar control for move and renames, and at the moment there are no plans to add it - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176961

However, there are requests for general "read-only" mode for GIt Integration - vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-194592